# how to pass parameters in shell script commands dynamically?

Tags: linux, unix

I want to call a shell script using java program and would like to pass parameters dynamically in one of the commands? Can anybody please help me with the java code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you had a look at [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=execute+linux+command+from+java) on this topic? What have you tried so far, and where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

such as~

```
private void execShell(String scriptPath, String ... para) {
    try {
        String[] cmd = new String[]{scriptPath};
        cmd=ArrayUtils.addAll(cmd,para);

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/chmod", "755",scriptPath);
        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();

        Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        ps.waitFor();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        String result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```